# git command line

Tags: git

I have been using eGit for eclipse so I do not know much about how to use git command line.

Now I got into some issue with eGit and would like to use native git commands to push and pull the updates.

So I opened the git bash and and typed  `$ git pull`

```
$ git pull
error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v2.0.2.84 does not point to a valid object!
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you're probably in the wrong directory.

Comment: Are you going to tell us what it says or are we guessing? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Permission denied (publickey)": don' t forget that EGit defines where to find your public/private ssh key (from [Egit user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)):

[image: EGit ssh config]

In a git bash, you need to make sure your id_rsa(.pub) files are under `$HOME/.ssh`.
If it is a msysgit Windows cmd shell, you need to define `%HOME%`.